# Make numbered grid overlay with different colours showing the frequency of data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I would like to create a grid overlay. Each grid cell should be numbered and showing frequency of some data using different colours. The grid is over a shapefile of an area.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck

Comment: I made the grids but now am unable to have them numbered. i am training myself so these are things i have never done before

Answer (score 1):

1. Find Create polygon graticule algorithm in processing toolbox (you have to install SAGA GIS before see: [Enabling SAGA in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87065/enabling-saga-in-qgis)). Set the *Output extent*, *Division Width* and *Division Height* on the Parameters panel. Output extent should be a bit larger than the extent of the point layer.
   [image]
   Each polygon will have three attributes: ID, ROW and COL in the new Rectangle graticule layer.
2. I suppose you have point data (if you have polygons generate centroid to work with points). From the vector menu choose Analysis Tools -> Count points in polygon
   [image]
   You get a new *Count* layer, which is a copy of the graticule layer but a new column (NUMPOINTS) is added to the attribute table with the number of point in each polygons.
   [image]
3. Create a thematic map based on the *NUMPOINTS* column of the *Count* layer.
   [image]
   Customize the the number of classes, colors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally I may suggest implementing the following workflow

**Step 1.** Create grid with `Vector > Research Tools > Create Grid...`, use the Point Extent as a *Grid extent*. For more details check the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html?highlight=create%20grid#create-grid).

**Step 2.** Apply one of the approaches described in these threads [Calculating point layer values within polygon features in QGIS 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305165/calculating-point-layer-values-within-polygon-features-in-qgis-2) or [Updating field to give count of points in polygon using STIntersects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44526/updating-field-to-give-count-of-points-in-polygon-using-stintersects). The *KISS principle* will lead you to applying @TeddyTedTed's answer, e.g. [`'Join attributes by location (summary)'`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary)

**Step 3.** Proceed with `RMC > Symbology > Graduated`, actually what @Zoltan defined as *Step 3* in his answer.

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Tutorials and Tips | Performing Spatial Joins (QGIS3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html)

Comment: Thanks so much guys.

Comment: Always welcome. Please accept one of the answers as a valid one